# Page refreshing on submit button, need it to hide form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I thought this would be the best place to ask this question. So I am currently in development of a website. Just ran into a few issues. Whenever I hit submit on an input box, instead of hiding that form and showing the next it keeps refreshing the page. Which is weird because if I browse the page locally and not on my server everything works as I need it too. I'll go ahead and post my code in hopes someone may know my issue. Thank you in advance!

Here is the button:

```
 <form id="firstForm">
            <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
              <label for="InputUsername">Username</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InputUsername" id="InputUsername"
                       placeholder="Username">
      </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Connect</button>
    </form>
```

Here is the Jquery:

```
$("#firstForm").validate({ rules: { InputUsername: { required: true, minlength: 1 } }, messages: { InputUsername: "Enter a valid username/email" }, submitHandler: function (form) { $(\'#firstForm\').fadeOut(function () { $(\'#secondForm\').fadeIn().removeClass(\'hidden\');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not strange. a **type `submit`** `<button>` will trigger a form action - unless you specify in your code an `Event.preventDefault()`

or if you specify strictly that it's a *type button* `<button type="button">Connect</button>` than the form will not submit and you can move on with your `.validate(` JS script.

Comment: Would I add this after the submitHandler? I appreciate the fast support! I am fairly new to jquery so I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to use an `event.preventDefault()` or `return false` in the button action function that you write as the submit button will trigger the form action otherwise.

```
$("#firstForm").submit(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  //Some action code here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use preventDefault to not to trigger the reload action:

```
$("#firstForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}).validate({...});
```